# How to use webpack to resolve ES6 imports without transpiling

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-module-loader

I want to split my javascript code into modules and resolve the `import`s with webpack to bundle all modules into a single file.

This works well with `babel-loader`, however, I don't want any transpilation but simple bundling - My modules contain plain ES6 code and only target ES6 compatible browsers.

What are my options?

Comment: There are no ES6 compatible browsers yet.

Comment: @Bergi Not 100% compatible, but current browsers [support almost all features](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Comment: Except modules, that is. For bundling, you'll need to transpile the module syntax, there's not really a way around it. You can instruct babel not to transpile anything else, of course.

Comment: Webpack 2 understands ES6 imports - it's not fully released/stable yet, but I think you can get it on NPM if you specify the version (the latest one is `2.1.0-beta.4`).

Comment: Am looking for this too as I can deploy on NodeJS